# Use current document keys in mongo aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, match, aggregate

I am working on a query that will sort my orders, for this I am using mongo aggregate with the following options.

```
$match
$lookup
$unwind
$sort
$skip
$limit
```

My whole query look like this.

```
[
        { "$match": query },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "orderstatuslogs",
                "localField": "_id",
                "foreignField": "orderId",
                "as": "filtered_statuses"
            }
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "orderstatuslogs",
                "localField": "_id",
                "foreignField": "orderId",
                "as": "order_statuses"
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind": "$filtered_statuses"
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                'filtered_statuses.status': status
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": { 'filtered_statuses.createdAt': sort }
        },
        { '$skip': skip },
        { "$limit": limit },
    ]
```

The current problem I am facing is on the second `$match`, `'filtered_statuses.status': status`.
The matching status should from the current document, some thing like that `$order_status`, we have key called `order_status` in every document and I want to use that key for the matching but I don't understand how to use that key.

My whole document look like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3496e9bf9c0a1b0a4bbdd1"),
    "products" : [ 
        ObjectId("5d3496e9bf9c0a1b0a4bbdd0")
    ],
    "isGiftCard" : true,
    "order_status" : "NEW",
    "total_price" : 240,
    "discount" : 0,
    "isConcierge" : false,
    "note" : "",
    "time" : "2019-05-12T10:28:43.316Z",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5cfcaf6d249ff4a6340d9385"),
    "trackId" : "891383",
    "isPackaged" : false,
    "sender_details" : ObjectId("5cfcaf6d249ff4a6340d9385"),
    "timeSlot" : ObjectId("5cfcfc2e2ae5a0e3d43af363"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-07-21T16:46:33.859Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-07-21T17:26:34.243Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5cfcfbf32ae5a0e3d43af35e"),
    "recipient_details" : ObjectId("5d349cc5a8f5cf1d345934d8"),
    "delivery_method" : ObjectId("5cfcfbb32ae5a0e3d43af35a"),
    "gift_card" : ObjectId("5d0107009786972878fcf811"),
    "gift_card_text" : "Eid Mabrook",
    "payment" : ObjectId("5d349cc8a8f5cf1d345934d9"),
    "payment_type" : ObjectId("5cfcfb802ae5a0e3d43af358"),
    "filtered_statuses" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d349cd5a8f5cf1d345934da"),
        "status" : "NEW",
        "active" : true,
        "userId" : ObjectId("5cfcaf6d249ff4a6340d9385"),
        "orderId" : ObjectId("5d3496e9bf9c0a1b0a4bbdd1"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-07-21T17:11:49.796Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-07-21T17:11:49.796Z"),
        "__v" : 0
    },
    "order_statuses" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d349cd5a8f5cf1d345934da"),
            "status" : "NEW",
            "active" : true,
            "userId" : ObjectId("5cfcaf6d249ff4a6340d9385"),
            "orderId" : ObjectId("5d3496e9bf9c0a1b0a4bbdd1"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-07-21T17:11:49.796Z"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-07-21T17:11:49.796Z"),
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

As you see in my current document I have `order_status` and I want to use the same key in the `$match` query to filtered my certain results.

Can anyone help me with it?

I've searched a lot for it but didn't find the correct approach for it.

Thanks guys in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use the `let` key in the `$lookup` stage in order to create variables that you can refer into the `$match` stage.

Second, you should use the `$match` stage in the `pipeline` key of the `$lookup`:

```
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "orderstatuslogs",
                "let": { order_status: "$order_status" }, // $order_status will refer to the order_status field in the main document
                "localField": "_id",
                "foreignField": "orderId",
                "as": "filtered_statuses",
                "pipeline": {
                    "$match": {
                        $expr: { $eq: [ "$status", "$$order_status" ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Finally, you can remove the second $match stage as it's not needed anymore.